# endless authorization loop when using installable trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

A simple web app is supposed to send a static email every hour. I use an installable trigger to accomplish this. When the web app is first called, the user is asked to authorize the web app. However, after authorization, the script is asked to re-authorize in an endless loop. How can I avoid this?

```
function doGet(e) {
  var params = JSON.stringify(e);

    ScriptApp.newTrigger('email')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(1)
      .create();

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('looks like it worked');

  }

function email(){  GmailApp.sendEmail('test@example.com', 'Subject line', "works");}
```

I expect the script to ask for authorization once, then install the trigger under the authorized user and send the email every hour

Comment: Although I'm not sure, script triggers might be the problem. You might not be able to create triggers for the end user using the web app. Also, Have you declared scopes in the manifest file manually?

Comment: The code is installing a trigger every time that the published URL is being called, and it's not testing for whether a trigger is already installed.  How is the request to the published URL being made?  Depending upon how the url is being requested, if the browser were getting refreshed, or it's being called with code, it might be getting triggered multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function isTrigger(funcName){
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
function doGet(e) {
  var params = JSON.stringify(e);
  if(!isTrigger('email')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('email').timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
  }
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('looks like it worked');

}
```